# socket.io Send message to particular user

Tags: node.js, socket.io, private-messaging

Could someone tell me what's wrong with my code? I'm trying to send a private message from one user to another using socket.io. I think the problem is somewhere with the line

```
io.sockets.socket(targetUser).emit('private message', tstamp(), socket.nickname, linkify(msg));
```

The problem is that the message isn't getting through to the client, or at least not getting appended to the div. I'm not sure how to troubleshoot exactly where the problem is.

The relevant code is below - I can add the entire code if that's not enough..:

Thanks for the help. I'm learning node.js and socket.io - though it's slow going!

on the client (send):

```
    function startPrivateChat(targetUser, sendingUser){
        if(targetUser !=sendingUser){
        var privateMessage1="starting private chat with " + targetUser + ". My name is " + sendingUser;
        var chatBoxId= targetUser + 'ChatBox';
        $("#content").append('<div class="chatBox" id="' + chatBoxId + '">' + sendingUser + ', ' + targetUser + '</div>');
        $('#' + chatBoxId).append('new private chat');
        $('#' + chatBoxId).dialog();
        privateMessage(tstamp(), myNick, privateMessage1);
        //socket.emit('private message', targetUser, privateMessage1);
        clear();    
        }
    }
```

Server:

```
socket.on('private message', function(targetUser,msg) {        
    io.sockets.socket(targetUser).emit('private message', tstamp(), socket.nickname, linkify(msg));
    updateLog('private message', socket.nickname, msg);
   });
```

on the client (recieve):

```
socket.on('private message', privateMessage);
function privateMessage (msg_time, from, msg) {
      $('#chatLogDiv').append($('<p>').append($('<small>').text(msg_time)).append($('<b>').text(from), linkify(msg)));
    }
```

Comment: Could you add the complete code, preferably on Pastebin

Comment: chat_server.js    [link](http://pastebin.com/nxHdzHDg)
example_chat.tpl.php  [link](http://pastebin.com/t0h7rSFv)

Comment: The code runs fine. Only modification made was to include the jquery library and exclude the php code that calls drupal_add_library and the drupal_add_js methods.

Comment: still not working. The jquery library is already included, and I commented out the two lines you mentioned (though I need them), and I still don't see anything on the recieving client

Answer (score 0):

I got this working!

On node.js-server:

```
    socket.on("SendMessage", function (value) {
        var userIdToRecieve = theOnlyUserToRecieveString;
        io.sockets.emit("SendAMessage", socket.userId, value, userIdToRecieve);
    });
```

On the client javascript side:

```
socket.on("SendAMessage", function (userId, value, userIdToRecieve) {
    // Write to the conversation window

    if (userIdToRecieve == myLocalUserID) {
        console.log("I shalleth recieve");
    }

});
```